# Collisions in processing

Tags: java, processing, collision

My game is a shooting game for school. I need help on the collision between my bullet and my enemy. I have placed the bullet class with my player but for some reason it keeps on passing through it and not disappearing. The first example below shows the weapon class which is for the bullet and the one underneath that is the main.

```
class Weapons{
  PImage bullet;
  int speed; 
  int imageSize = 20;
  float x = 20;
  float y = 20;
  float m;
  int damage = 5;
  int[] src = new int[2];
  float[] dest = new float[2]; 
  

  
  
  Weapons(int x, int y){
    speed = 12;
    dest[0] = mouseX;
    dest[1] = mouseY;
    src[0] = x;
    src[1] = y;
    m = (dest[1]-src[1]) / (dest[0]-src[0]);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    bullet = loadImage("bullet.png");
    bullet.resize(imageSize,imageSize);
    
  }
  
  boolean shooting(){
    image(bullet, x, y); // if attack is true then renfer the image
    x += speed;
    y = (m * (x - dest[0])) + dest[1];
    return (x > width || y > height);   
    
  }
  
  boolean crash(Enemy enemies) {
  //// return the result of checking if the plane has crashed into the bird
  return abs(this.x-enemies.x) < bullet.width && abs(this.y - enemies.y) < bullet.height;
  
}
  

  
  }
```

```
Maincharacter MC;
Goal G; 
ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Weapons> bullets = new ArrayList<>();


final int Playing = 0; 
final int Finish = 1; 

int gameMode = Playing; 


//Enemy[] enemies = new Enemy[10];

PImage background; // creating background 
int bgX = 0;


void setup(){
  size(800,500);
  MC = new Maincharacter(100,3); 
  //E1 = new Enemy();
  G = new Goal(100,20);
  
  background = loadImage("Battleground1.png");
  background.resize(width*2,height); //set image to be same size as the canvas
  
  for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){ // i represent how many enemy I want.
    enemies.add(new Enemy((int)random(200,850), (int)random(0, height- 150) ) );
  }


//for(int i=0 ; i < enemies.length ; i++){ 
//enemies[i] = new Enemy(); }

}


void draw(){
  if(gameMode == Playing){
    background();
    MC.display(); 
    G.display();
    
    for(Enemy E : enemies){
      E.update();
      if (MC.crash(E)){
        gameMode = Finish; 
    }
    }
    
      for(Weapons W: bullets){
      W.update();
      if(enemies.crash(W)){ // doesnt exist
        gameMode = Finish;
      }
 }

//  for(int i=0 ; i < enemies.length ; i++){ 
//enemies[i].update(); }

}}


void keyPressed(){
  // creating  the movemnt for my main charcter
  MC.move();
    if (keyCode == RIGHT || keyCode == 68 ){   
      MC.x += 10; 
    } else if (keyCode == UP || keyCode == 87) {
      MC.y -=10;
    } else if (keyCode == LEFT || keyCode == 65){
      MC.x -= 10;
    } else if(keyCode == DOWN || keyCode == 83 ){
      MC.y += 10;
    } else if (keyCode == 32) { // space bar
      MC.attack_function(); // call attack function to create bullet object
    }// make an attack 
     
  }
  
  
void mousePressed(){ // when mouse is pressed call attack function to create bullet object
  MC.attack_function();
  
}




void background(){
//scrolling background image
  image(background, bgX, height/2); //draw image to fill the canvas
  //draw image again off the right of the canvas
  
  image(background, bgX+background.width, height/2);    
  
  bgX -= 4;
 
  if(bgX == -background.width ) //if first image completely off the canvas
  {
    bgX=0; //reset back to initial value background
  }
  
}
```

What I want is to have bullet colliding with the enemies and then disappearing.

Comment: "giving me errors." - please [edit] and show those errors.

Comment: Is your `bullet.width` and `bullet.height` smaller than the speed? If so then one step in speed calculation "teleports" the bullet from one side of the enemy to the other without touching it.

Comment: @cyberbrain No my bullet height and width isnt smaller than the speed.

Comment: @hc_dev I delete those errors I cant get them back so far this is the only code that is close to getting what i need sorry about that

Comment: in your constructor `Weapons`:  where do `mouseX` and `mouseY` come from?

Comment: @cyberbrain From the weapons x and y (the source) to the mouses x and y (the destination) if that helps

Comment: What I meant: your code from the question does not show any declaration of `mouseX` and `mouseY` so it will not compile - but if we should help you, please provide a [mre] so we can find out what's wrong.

Comment: @cyberbrain mouseX and mouseY are system variables in the Processing language:https://processing.org/reference/mouseX.html.  I agree that we still need a minimal example; posted code will not run.  I think there may be other classes for Maincharacter, Enemy, and Goal that we are not being shown.

Comment: @apodidae yh there are other class in my code that are not being shown should I bring it up?

Comment: @cyberbrain yh there are other class in my code that are not being shown should I bring it up?

Comment: Unfortunately I read that "processing" tag too late, I'm not familiar with it. But: you check the collision in the method `Weapons.crash` - is this called anywhere? If it is called in your code, you should show that code too.

Comment: @cyberbrain weapons.crash is not been called in anywhere in my code

Comment: but is it called from _anywhere_ ? If it is not called at all, this would explain, why you do not detect any hits - the collision detection is done in that method, if it is not called at all then no collision detection happens. (Also `Weapons` does not derive from any class nor implement any interface and the method has default visibility, so a call from "outside" gets unlikelier.)

Comment: @cyberbrain i did call it but it saying that crash doesn't ( I have update the code in  the main class above).

Comment: so I have to keep on asking ;) (I'm not familiar with processing, sorry): is that `draw` method actually called, where you call the `crash` method? Looks like this is called, but did you actually have a breakpoint or log statement in there to prove it?

Comment: @cyberbrain yeah the draw method get called but the crash method doesnt it keeps saying does not exist.

Comment: Ok, first of all: reading your code is a bit confusing me because you don't have a common style for your variable and field names. You should let all your variable and field names start with a lowercase letter - but it is not the source of the problem. Anyways for the problem I will post a real answer now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the method `enemies.crash(W)` but `enemies` is some collection of `Enemy` instances. `Enemy` does not provide the method `crash` as well.

You have to loop for each of your enemies all of your weapons and call the method `crash` on the `Weapon` instance giving the current enemy, something like:

```java
for (Enemy enemy: enemies){
  enemy.update();
  if (mainCharacter.crash(enemy)) {
    gameMode = Finish; 
  }
  for (Weapons weapon: bullets) {
    weapon.update();
    if (weapon.crash(enemy)) {
      gameMode = Finish;
      // TODO: are you sure that killing an enemy finishes the game?
    }
  }
}
```

(Please note that I used `mainCharacter` instead of `MC` here for better readability.)

Comment: If this answer is the solution to the problem you posted (not to your full program of course), consider to accept it to signal others that the question could be answered with this.